# Four-vector addition in Minkowski space

Tags: special-relativity

I've been reading that Minkowski space is a real vector space; atleast in flat space-time. So that means that we should be able to define vector addition, scalar multiplication, etc. But since four-vectors in space-time are events, how does adding two events make sense? More importantly, what is the meaning of the resultant vector?

Comment: Let me ask you the same question, but for the plane. We setup Cartesian coordinates (x,y) which represents a point on the plane. Yet we add two points too! What are we doing there?

Comment: *"But since four-vectors in space-time are events"*  - [Does spacetime position not form a four-vector?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/192886/9887)

Answer (score 6):

Minkowski spacetime is an **affine space** not a **vector space**: vectors acts as group of translations on the spacetime moving events, but vectors are not events. If you arbitraily fix an origin $O$, there is exactly one vector $v(e)$ joining $O$ to every event $e$ of the spacetime. In this sense there is a one-to-one correspondence between events and four-vectors, but it strongly depends on the choice of the preferred origin.

If you also fix a pseudo-orthogonal basis, the components of $v(e)$ with respect to that basis are just the Minkowskian coordinates of $e$.

Comment: I think the question on four-vector addition, scalar multiplication, etc was not answered. Wikipedia says: "Four-vectors have the same linearity properties as Euclidean vectors in three dimensions. They can be added in the usual entrywise way and similarly scalar multiplication by a scalar."

Comment: The statement "Minkowski spacetime is an affine space not a vector space" can be misleading as four-vectors are defined for Minkowski spacetime. Wiki: "Four-vectors describe, for instance, position x_i in spacetime modeled as Minkowski space."